# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IFabricNodeContextResult2

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am getting the following exception when starting a Stateful Service which prevents the service from fully starting.  How do I resolve this exception and get the service to start?

> System.InvalidCastException
>         HResult=0x80004002
>         Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IFabricNodeContextResult2'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{472BF2E1-D617-4B5C-A91D-FABED9FF3550}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>         Source=mscorlib
>         StackTrace:
>          at System.StubHelpers.InterfaceMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr pUnk,
>   IntPtr itfMT, IntPtr classMT, Int32 flags)
>          at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeRuntime.FabricEndGetNodeContext(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context)
>          at System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.NativeFabricRuntimeFactory.GetNodeContextEndWrapper(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context)
>          at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext
>   context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.RuntimeContext.d__14.MoveNext()
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.ServiceRuntime.d__0.MoveNext()
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>          at PrintFileStatelessService.Program.Main() in C:\MyCompany\Current\ServiceFabric\MyCompany.MicroServices\PrintFileStatelessService\Program.cs:line
>   35

Here are the nuget packages that I have on this service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric" version="6.1.467" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data" version="3.0.467" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal" version="3.0.467" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.FabricTransport.Internal" version="3.0.467" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services" version="3.0.467" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting" version="3.0.467" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

And here is the code

```
namespace PrintFileStatefulService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An instance of this class is created for each service replica by the Service Fabric runtime.
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class PrintFileStatefulService : StatefulService, IPrintFileService
    {
        public PrintFileStatefulService(StatefulServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        { }

        public Task GeneratePrintFile(Guid duesbillingId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., HTTP, Service Remoting, WCF, etc.) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// For more information on service communication, see https://aka.ms/servicefabricservicecommunication
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
        {
            //return new ServiceReplicaListener[0];
            return new[]
            {
                new ServiceReplicaListener(context => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context))
            };
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Please state a clear question.

Comment: Needs much more background information to understand what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and found [this thread](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/issues/69). Turns out the local service fabric SDK needed updating, once I did that it started working again.

Download link for the service fabric SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK

(Or if you don't like clicking a link that wants to install something, go here and find the (same) link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started)

Answer (score 8):

Try updating the Service Fabric SDK on your PC, weird errors sometimes occur if your SDK does not match the nuget package you use.