# Can I call a stateless service with RPC from outside of a cluster but in the same local network?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-cloud-services

On my local machine in Visual Studio 2017, I created solution based on the .NET Core Stateless Service template, and added  Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime package to accept remote calls through RPC.

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();
}
```

Then I added interface ITestAccUp in a separate project:

```
public interface ITestAccUp : IService
{
    Task NotifyAsync();
}
```

I added implementation of the interface to the stateless service, and created one more project, a .NET Core console client to run the service. The console is going to be run outside a cluster.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ITestAccUp testAccUpClient = ServiceProxy.Create<ITestAccUp>(new Uri("fabric:/SFAccountUpTest/Stateless1"));

    testAccUpClient.NotifyAsync().Wait();
}
```

However, when I run it I got the error *"InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IFabricTestManagementClient4'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B96AA7D4-ACC0-4814-89DC-561B0CBB6028}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."*, 
though Named Application fabric:/SFAccountUpTest/Stateless1 seems to be up and running.

I guess the problem is RPC calls are just made for calling services inside SF clusters, not outside. Is it possible to make an RPC call outside a cluster, or is it necessary to build some sort of web API to make a service call?

[image: solution structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're on the same network, you can call Services and Actors by using SF Remoting from other applications. For example, see [this demo](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/tree/master/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors.Demo/TestClient) project which does so for testing purposes.

Make sure you use the same DLL that holds the interface definition from both the client and the service project. (It works different from WCF, where a proxy could be generated independently from the service, by using wsdl.)

Maybe you're running into an issue, like [this](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/783) one, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49039954/5946937) one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's running at the same computer. 
Yes, it's the same solution and the DLL is shared between this 2 projects. 
Regarding this 2 links solving similar issue: 1) it's void parameter-less method so there is no type cast, 2) All projects share same latest version of Service.Remoting librabry 3.2.176 and same SDK .net core 2.1. I've attached screenshot to the question.

I think if the RPC call allowed indeed, my problem is rather a problem of some sort of system permissions to make the call

Comment: Try using the same net core app version everywhere as well. Your service has 2.1.3.

Comment: I downgraded to Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services package to 3.0.472 and make it SDK 2.1 (vs 2.1.3) and after that it started working right indeed. I'm a bit shocked over how brittle the Microsoft SDK is: discrepancy in even a minor version makes client and service incompatible, with no clear message about what happened. That frightens me as a beginner in Service Fabric development

Comment: @LoekD This information appears to contradict your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49427173/2602982 , which also asks about service remoting from outside the cluster. Am I missing some nuance in one of the questions, other than the single network constraint in this question?

Comment: I believe I answered that from the perception of making calls from outside of the network.There wasn't a lot of info in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is kinda old, but the way I solved this problem was to make sure I was using the "V2" remoting stack ([details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#upgrade-from-remoting-v1-to-remoting-v2))

Basically you need to edit your ServiceManifest.xml to use this as an Endpoint:

```
<Resources>
  <Endpoints>
    <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpointV2" />  
  </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

And add the `[assembly]` attribute to your remoting interface (above `namespace`).

Example:

```
...
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.FabricTransport;

[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(RemotingListenerVersion = RemotingListenerVersion.V2, RemotingClientVersion = RemotingClientVersion.V2)]
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IMyService : IService
    {
        ...
```